# VBA function using multiple range inputs and multiple outputs

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function in excel VBA that calculates the coefficients of the equation of a plane using 9 inputs (coordinates of 3 points) from a range in a worksheet. Here is what I have so far but that doesn't seem to work:

```
Function Plane_Eq_3Pts(ByVal X1 As Range, ByVal Y1 As Range, ByVal Z1 As Range, ByVal X2 As Range, ByVal Y2 As Range, ByVal Z2 As Range, ByVal X3 As Range, ByVal Y3 As Range, ByVal Z3 As Range) As Variant()

Dim Eq(0 To 3) As Variant

Eq(0) = (Y2 - Y1) * (Z3 - Z1) - (Y3 - Y1) * (Z2 - Z1)
Eq(1) = (Z2 - Z1) * (X3 - X1) - (Z3 - Z1) * (X2 - X1)
Eq(2) = (X2 - X1) * (Y3 - Y1) - (X3 - X1) * (Y2 - Y1)
Eq(3) = -(Eq(0) * X1 + Eq(1) * Y1 + Eq(2) * Z1)

Plane_Eq_3Pts = Eq

End Function
```

I have tried using Control+Shift+Enter when using the function above and selecting 4 cells however, I keep getting a #VALUE on all 4 of the selected cells. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you provide a test input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function *(exactly as coded)* is using a **one dimensional array**  .  This is appropriate for a **row** output and in *Excel 365* it will spill into a dynamic row:

[image]

If you want it to spill into a column in *Excel 365* then `TRANSPOSE()` could be used:

```
=TRANSPOSE(Plane_Eq_3Pts(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9))
```

[image]

If you are not using *Excel 365* then the function must be array-entered.

**EDIT#1:**

Lets take the row case.  First hi-light cells **D3** through **G3**.  Second click in the `Formula Bar`.  Third type the formula with array-entry.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 if that helps. Can you please elaborate on what array-entered means?

Comment: @Jamaleas  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you. I had this function in an Add-In so I had to declare it as a public function in order for it work. Thank you for the transpose function also, that makes my life a lot easier!!